# Bash variable interpolation confusion

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

I'm trying to understand Bash variable interpolation.

I want to use `readlink` to show the path a symlink points to.

If I use a string it works.

```
$ echo "$(readlink -- ~/.gitconfig)"
/Users/jord/.dotfiles/gitconfig
```

For some reason it doesn't work when I try to use a variable instead of a string.

```
$ file="~/.gitconfig"
$ echo "$(readlink -- $file)"
```

Nothing is printed except a blank line.

If I do the same thing, but with `dirname` (as an example) instead, the variable interpolation works as I would expect.

```
$ file="~/.gitconfig"
$ echo "$(dirname -- "$file")"
~
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why `echo "$(dirname -- "$file")"`? Why not just `dirname -- "$file"`?

Comment: Copy and paste from a different example :)

Comment: Please see this: [What is wrong with `echo $(stuff)` or `echo \`stuff\``?](https://superuser.com/q/1352850/432690)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~` in quotes stays literal `~`. The [relevant part of Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Tilde-Expansion.html) starts with

> If a word begins with an unquoted tilde character (`~`), …

To see the difference, compare:

```
file="~/.gitconfig"
echo "$file"
file=~/".gitconfig"
echo "$file"
```

In your first example `$(…)` works first and in its context `~` is unquoted. So it gets expanded as you expect.

Your `$file`, when it "doesn't work" contains literal `~`. [POSIX standard says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06):

> The order of word expansion shall be as follows:
>
> Tilde expansion […], parameter expansion […], command substitution […], and arithmetic expansion […] shall be performed, beginning to end. […]

Because tilde expansion is performed before parameter expansion, a variable that expands to `~/something` doesn't expand further to a proper path.

Remember `~` or `~/` is special to your shell in some circumstances but to (almost?) any other tool it's not a valid path. When it works, it's because the shell does its "magic" first and the other tool sees the already expanded path (like `/Users/jord`).

Note in your last example tilde expansion *doesn't* work, you still get the literal `~` and it's too late for the shell to do something about it without additional tricks (like `eval`). `dirname` doesn't complain because it works with strings. It doesn't care if the given path is valid, existent etc. It basically just searches for the last non-slash component and discards it with trailing slashes (if any).

See also [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/399439/108618).

Comment: Thank you. This makes perfect sense now you've explained it so well.